# having problems to group products by time elapsed between Now and when they was created

Tags: ruby, loops, collections

I am looping through the collection of all the products. I would like to group these products in three or four categories depending on the time elapsed between now and when they were created...

This is the code I am writing:

```
def group_products (products) 
    products.each do |product|
     @counter = =+ 1
     if ((Time.now - product.created_at)/60).to_i < 50000
         @group_one =+ 1

     elsif ((Time.now - product.created_at)/60).to_i > 50000 
         @group_two =+ 1
     else 
         @group_three =+ 1
     end 
end 
   [@group_one, @group_two, @group_three, @counter]
end
```

This code does only run the loop once. And all the groups get 1 what means that the conditional is not working properly. The counter also gets 1 only. I am expecting to have the code go through the collection one by one and assign each product to a particular group depending on the condition. I would like the method to return an array of the categories and the counter... There is certainly something I am not doing right here. Maybe there is a better way to do it. Please I need some help.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
count += 1
```

rather than

```
count =+ 1
```

You keep assigning +1 to your instance variables, hence the results.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the spaceship operator along with group_by:

```
products = [1,2,3,4,5]
groups = products.group_by { |product| product <=> 3 }
groups.map { |k, v| v.size } + [products.size]
#=> [2, 1, 2, 5]
```

no loops though...

Edit: here is how it would look in this case:

```
groups = products.group_by { |product| ((Time.now - product.created_at) / 60).to_i <=> 50000 }
```

Edit 2(solution to more general problem laid out in the comments):

```
products = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ranges = [1..2, 3..3, 4..5]
groups = products.group_by do |product|
  ranges.find { |r| r.cover? product }
end
groups.map { |k, v| v.size } + [products.size]
#=> [2, 1, 2, 5]
```

Edit 3(cleaner map):

```
groups.values.map(&:size) + [products.size]
```

Edit 4:

So with your data it would look like this:

```
ranges = [1..15, 16..60, 61..120]
groups = products.group_by do |product|
  ranges.find { |r| r.cover?(((Time.now - product.created_at) / 60).to_i) }
end
groups.values.map(&:size) + [products.size]
```

Comment: @Seph... Thank you for suggesting this other approach. However, I am grouping tweets according to the time elapsed since they were created. So I have the first group (within 15 minutes), the second group (16 minutes to 60 minutes ago), the thirst group (61 minutes to 120 minutes ago) and the fourth group ... the rest.

Comment: So I first calculate time_elapsed = Time.now - tweet.created_at (I get an integer)... For each tweet, I check if the time_elapsed falls within a range (1...15; 16 .. 60, etc)....

Comment: How will these conditionals be combined within a group_by method... ? Should one introduce some case when statement in the block after group_by, or should one use if elsif statement... Or would you think of another trick ? Best regards

Comment: @user3669547 - okay, this will not solve the problem laid out in your comments. Please see edit2.

Comment: Thank you @Seph. Your solution is very clear and very elegant. I will go for it. This is great ruby code. I am only concerned about performance... and where to do such group.

Comment: I am retrieving tweets based on a search keyword provided by the user and then I am displaying these tweets and showing a graph according to time elapsed since the tweet was created. With my reasoning so far, there are three places where the program loops through all the records in the initial tweets array obtained from twitter. so I fetch the tweets, I loop through them in order to group them, and in the view I again loop through the array of tweets to display them. I was hoping to find a solution with maximum of two  loops through all the records to cut time spent in processing things.

Comment: I thought of a solution where the grouping only happens in the view when I am iterating over the records in order to display them... however, I am worried that too much business logic would be put in the view... May be with a helper method, one can get every record as the iteration goes on for display and return in the end an array of groups sizes which I would like to use to build the graph. However this seems like having views do too much... Do you have any suggestion in this regards?